# Java Dynamic Proxy. Зачем использовать тут прокси-объект?

Tags: java, aop

Изучаю прокси-объекты, но не до конца понимаю, для чего они нужны. Вот одно из объяснений:

Есть интерфейс (обязательное условие):

```
public interface IPerson {
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
    public void rename(String new_name);
}
```

Есть класс, его исполняющий (тоже обязательное условие):

```
public class Person implements IPerson {
    private String name;

    public  String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public  void   setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void rename(String new_name) {
        if (!new_name.equals(name))
            this.name = new_name;
    }
}
```

Есть вот такой класс (тоже обязателен, его называют InvocationHandler)

```
public class NeverSleepingEye implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler {
    private Object obj;

    public NeverSleepingEye(Object f1) {
        obj = f1;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, java.lang.reflect.Method method,  Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("NeverSleepingEye invoke : " +  method.getName());
        return method.invoke(obj, args);
    }
}
```

Это пример использования:

```
Person person = new Person();

IPerson personproxy = (IPerson) 
Proxy.newProxyInstance(Person.class.getClassLoader(), 
                           Person.class.getInterfaces(),
                           new NeverSleepingEye(person));

personproxy.setName("Гриша");
String h = personproxy.getName();
personproxy.rename("Вася");
```

Меня интересует конкретно пример использования. Здесь создается объект типа `Person`, а дальше создается ссылка типа `IPerson` и, насколько я поняла, ей возвращается прокси-объект типа `Person`. С помощью этой ссылки дальше вызываюся методы. Но зачем создавать прокси-объект, если уже создан обычный объект и можно вызывать те же методы через него? Только лишь для того, чтобы в методе `invoke()` дополнить как-то вызов этих методов? А если в методе `invoke()` ничего не происходит, кроме вызова требуемых методов есть смысл вообще создавать прокси-объект? И я не понимаю, в каких случаях я могу сказать: "Здесь требуется создание прокси-объекта"?

Comment: Такие прокси объекты обычно используются в аспектно ориентированном программировании, например, мы можем добавить, что бы на каждый вызов метода для объекта Person производилось логирование, либо ограничить доступ к вызовам метода и т.д. В Вашем случае, прокси объект представляет из себя Big Bro, который следит и выводит сообщение при вызове любого метода класса Person

Comment: короче если ты хочешь что добавить сквозного в метод используется прокси объект, не только логирование, там еще куча всякого)))

Comment: и как видишь используется рефлексия

Comment: Прокси используется для того, чтобы добавить дополнительное поведение объекту, не меняя его исходный код.